# jboss7.1 + jsf2.0... + Intellij IDEA13.1

Tags: jsf-2, jboss

I have some problem with render my app. 
I have index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
   <f:view>
      <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

And web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jsf</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

All deploys are well. And my page opening in browser. But i don`t see anything there. When i looking on HTML what botted i see:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"><head></head><body><f:view>
      <h:outputlabel value="Hello, world"></h:outputlabel>
   </f:view>
</body></html>
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Change it to. Xhtml and change default suffix to. Xhtml aswell lower case x

Comment: I change default suffix but this isn`t help me. And what is "Change it to. Xhtml" what is it?

Comment: your files name ends in html, change it to xhtml - as you're using jsf it needs to be xhtml or confiugred to be jsp/jsf.. not html or nothing wil be picked up by the FacesServlet

Comment: Sorry this`s my wrong ( I wrote here index.html but realy is index.xhtml. I use Intellij Idea. It`s do it for me )) Do you have any idea?

Comment: Pretty sure it's your namespaces etc are old. Will look when home.

Comment: xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  - update your namespaces, the maven examples in IntelliJ have the old ones.